# Strange error in Eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse

I faced a strange error while working on android in Eclipse.The situation is like follows.I have a fully working project.While working on a activity java file, unfortunately  my system shut down.When I reopen the eclipse after opening the system, some of the java files of my project converted to ASCII characters.I dont have a back up also.Please help me.The resulting java file look like the following,

[image]

Comment: Have you opened the file outside of eclipse? Can you see the content there? For a backup check the local history in eclipse for that file. You might be able to restore some of the content... and what do you learn from the issue? Use a version control system to keep a backup...

Comment: Its not opened anywhere.System shut down so everything got closed abnormally.Yeah one thing I learned is to keep a back up each time when I add something important.But still then if any solution to this is available then It would be great.

Comment: As I asked: Have you checked if the file is really empty with a normal editor? Maybe it is just a problem with eclipse itself. Also: Check the local history to find a older state of the file.... helping would be so awesome if the people would read what I write...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to the above problem.Eclipse always saves the file in a local history based on the modified date and time.To retrieve the recently modified file from the local history, follow the steps,

1.Open the corrupted file with eclipse editor.

2.right click -> Team -> Show Local History“
View the result in ‘History View’

and based on the modified time open the file with a text editor and copy your original content.

**Another way**

Eclipse workspace-->.metadata-->.plugins-->org.eclipse.core.resources-->.history

you can find a list of folders named with few letters, use the “Date Modified” column and open the latest of those folders to get the recent files you were working on.In that folder, you can find some files with unusual naming, open the files with some text editor to find the file you are searching for, if possible try to match the file size.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Resource -> Text file encoding and then choose your encoding (UTF-8, etc.)

**EDIT :**

Another approach could be Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace and then choose your encoding here

Comment: Did you try to change and restart Eclipse ? It's weird, I can see my java files changed like you and then re-change them in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Yeah I restarted the eclipse several times but it gives me the same weird content.

Comment: If you open the file outside Eclipse, can you see the content ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29480/discussion-between-user2012-and-zouzou)